# Software to find metadata for mp3s with irrelevant filenames, fake metadata, or no metadata

Tags: windows, mp3, metadata-editor

I have a collection of music that have all been renamed by someone to meaningless titles such as File1.mp3, File2.mp3, File3.mp3, etc. which contain no relevant metadata. Is there a Windows application able to process the music file wave form and search online to automatically find music file metadata and add them to the mp3s?

Answer (score 3):

[MusicBrainz Picard](http://picard.musicbrainz.org/) "uses AcoustID audio fingerprints, allowing files to be identified by the actual music, even if they have no metadata."

It can be downloaded for Windows, OS X, and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of apps that do this. I write one: [bliss](https://www.blisshq.com). After pointing bliss at your root music folder(s), bliss will recognise untagged files and suggest tags on the *Untagged* page:

[image: List of untagged folders of albums]

Under the covers, bliss uses Acoustid to identify recordings, and then perform intersections on the result releases to identify the actual releases that the recordings collectively represent (i.e. albums).

Disclaimer: as above, I'm the developer and founder of the bliss project.